# Unable to delete and select from an ets table

Tags: erlang, elixir, ets

I am having trouble retrieving and deleting records from ETS.

After inserting them like:

```
:ets.insert(
  :table_name,
  {id, location, [name, x, z]}
)
```

I am unable to delete them like so:

```
:ets.delete(:table_name, id)
```

I have also tried and this doesn't return anything.

```
:ets.match(:table_name, {id, location, '_'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always can review the content of `:ets` with `:ets.foldl/3`

```elixir
ets = :ets.new(:table_name, [])

:ets.insert(ets, {1, 2, ["foo", 3, 4]})       
#⇒ true

:ets.foldl(&[&1|&2], [], ets)
#⇒ [{1, 2, ["foo", 3, 4]}]
```

`:ets.delete/2` works out of the box:

```elixir
:ets.delete ets, 1
#⇒ true
```

For `:ets.match/2` one should use *atoms* ([elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) differs from [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) in how to denote them) *and* specify what to return back.

```elixir
:ets.match(ets, {:_, :_, :'$1'})  
#⇒ [[["foo", 3, 4]]]

:ets.match(ets, {1, :'$1', :'$2'})
#⇒ [[2, ["foo", 3, 4]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an Elixir wrapper around ETS (and DETS), you can use [pockets](https://hex.pm/packages/pockets):

```
iex> Pockets.new(:table_name)
{:ok, :table_name}
iex> Pockets.put(:table_name, :id, "Foo")
:table_name
iex> Pockets.get(:table_name, :id)
"Foo"
```